# Response Assertion is failing with working RegEx when used correlation.

Tags: regex, jmeter, correlation, assertion

**Response data :** renderData":"{\"note\":\"test note\",\"color\":\"\",\"appHeight\":\"203px\",\"appWidth\":\"224px\",\"actionURI\":\"/static/nbapps/notepad/addNote.ejs\",\"mode\":\"INLINE\",\"annotationContainerId\":\"ebook_container\",\"pageXOffset\":0}"

**Regular Expression (it's working perfect) - renderData :** renderData":"([^}]+pageXOffset.+?})"

**Response Assertion (Text Response, contains are selected) - ${renderData} :** Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to contain /{\"note\":\"test note\",\"color\":\"\",\"appHeight\":\"203px\",\"appWidth\":\"224px\",\"actionURI\":\"/static/nbapps/notepad/addNote.ejs\",\"mode\":\"INLINE\",\"annotationContainerId\":\"ebook_container\",\"pageXOffset\":0}/

*why assertion is showing, text expected to contain, when the same text is available in response?*

Comment: I think you can use [JSON processing feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter+json) in JMeter (see the whole lot of questions on that).

Answer (score 1):

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide:

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
>
> a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

Given you use `Contains` - JMeter treats the pattern as Regular Expression, it doesn't match anything hence it fails.

So you have the following options:

1. If you extracted the "interesting" response bit into a JMeter Variable - you can apply assertion to the variable directly, configure Assertion as follows:

   - Apply to: JMeter Variable -> Reference Name from the Regular Expression Extractor
   - Pattern Matching Rules: Equals
   - Patterns to test: add your expected value:

     ```
     {\"note\":\"test note\",\"color\":\"\",\"appHeight\":\"203px\",\"appWidth\":\"224px\",\"actionURI\":\"/static/nbapps/notepad/addNote.ejs\",\"mode\":\"INLINE\",\"annotationContainerId\":\"ebook_container\",\"pageXOffset\":0}
     ```

     [image: Response Assertion applied to variable]

   Just make sure assertion goes **below** Regular Expression Extractor
2. You can apply assertion directly to the response, in that case choose "Substring" in the "Pattern Matching Rules"